# Pressed button after leaving messagebox in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In a binding to the button `DROP` function I have:

```
def on_click_button_drop(element):

    # ...

    if not db_name:
        print("db name empty")
        messagebox.showinfo("", "db name empty")
        return
# ...
button_drop.bind("<Button-1>", on_click_button_drop)
```

But after pressing `OK` in `messagebox.showinfo` the button left pressed...

[image 1](http://prntscr.com/426xct)
[image 2](http://prntscr.com/426wcu)

---

Full test code

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox

root = Tk()
root.grid()


def on_click_button_drop(element):
    db_name = entry_db_name.get()
    if not db_name:
        # print("db name empty")
        messagebox.showinfo("", "db name empty")
        return
    pass

label_db_name = Label(root, text="db name")
entry_db_name = Entry(root, width=20)
button_drop = Button(root, text="DROP", width=10)

label_db_name.pack()
entry_db_name.pack()
button_drop.pack()

button_drop.bind("<Button-1>", on_click_button_drop)

root.mainloop()
```

What to do to depress the button

Comment: this means that button's pressed callback did not end properly..Make sure that your callback end properly without any errors

Comment: Added a test code for python 3.3.5 Where this callback can fall in error?

Comment: I run it under under Windows 7 (if it means something).

Comment: Should I return something in `return-pass` section?

Comment: If you comment out `messagebox.showinfo("", "db name empty")`, the button will function normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve the desired effect use the `<ButtonRelease-1>` event, instead of `<Button-1>` event:

```
button_drop.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_click_button_drop)
```

Additionally, your `return` and `pass` statements are redundant, this is enough:

```
def on_click_button_drop(element):
    db_name = entry_db_name.get()
    if not db_name:
        # print("db name empty")
        messagebox.showinfo("", "db name empty")
```

Comment: This button-won't-return-after-messagebox issue seems to be wide-spread problem for people. It has taken me a lot of searching and various failures to find this perfect and simple solution, so brilliant to have such a simple answer.